# c++: vector gets unexpected data

Tags: c++, vector

When i'm calling to the function below, it adds my input to the vector, but consistently adds 6 extra cells to the vector. Any ideas why does it happening?

This is the relevant function:

```
void seperate_words(string str1, vector<struct wordstype> &vec1)
{
    string temp_str;
    string::iterator is=str1.begin();
    wordstype input_word;
    while (is<str1.end())
    {
        if (((*is)!='-')&&((*is)!='.')&&((*is)!=',')&&((*is)!=';')&&((*is)!='?')&&((*is)!='!')&&((*is)!=':'))
        {
            temp_str.push_back(*is);
            ++is;
        }
        else
        { 
            input_word.word=temp_str;
            vec1.push_back(input_word);
            is=str1.erase(is);
            temp_str.clear();
        }
    }
    input_word.word=temp_str;
    vec1.push_back(input_word);
    temp_str.clear();
}
```

the relevant interval of main program that calls the func is:

```
**while(end_flag==-1){
    cin>> temp_string;
    end_flag=temp_string.find(end_str);/*indicates whether the end sign is precieved*/
    seperate_words(temp_string,words_vecref);/*seperats the input into single words and inserts them into a vector*/
} 
int x=words_vec.size();
cout<<x<<" "<<std::endl;
for (vector<struct wordstype>::iterator p_it=words_vec.begin();p_it<words_vec.end();p_it++)
 {cout<<(*p_it).word<<" ";}**
```

for example: i'm walking down the street, should increase my vector size by only 6 elements(and not 12)

output expected:only six cells, in each oe of them will be a word from the input in the order of entry.

Comment: Your question is unclear, in part because the intent of your code fragment is unclear. Please provide a **complete**, **short** sample program that demonstrates the error you are having. Please copy-paste (not retype) that short program into your question. Please provide the output that you expect, and the output that you actually observe. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Do you mean that there are 6 more elements than you expect? If so, could you post some example input and output (and preferably a short, compilable program so we can reproduce what you're seeing)? Or do you mean that `vec1.capacity()` is larger than `vec1.size()`? That's to be expected if you use `push_back()`; vectors grow by a multiplicative factor to reduce the number of reallocations needed.

Comment: I just saw your update. I don't see any problem except what I already mentioned below. Are you certain that words_vec equals words_vecref? In the while loop you use words_vecref, while at the end you use words_vec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your string have six punctuation marks at the end?
When the text ends with a punctuation mark, you add an extra empty string to the vector ( because you unconditionally add to the vector outside the while loop)

If you have several of these you have several empty strings (this time inside the while loop).
These empty strings can also occur in the middle of the text.

This because you when pushing back don't test where you actually encountered some text.
You can fix this be testing whether temp_str is not empty before calling push_back in the while loop and after the while loop.

Comment: i followed your suggstion which sounds to me the most possible option to correct the code, but when i'm checking if the temp_str is empty it gets into a Infinite loop. why?  some code:     if(!temp_str.empty())
    {
        input_word.word=temp_str;
        vec1.push_back(input_word);
        temp_str.clear();
    }

Comment: You still need to do the erase. Otherwise your position won't increase. Now that I'm thinking about it, why do you actually erase (it doesn't really make sense to me since it is a local variable and you won't change the outside), and not just increment the position using ++is;

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to add elements to a vector whose current capacity can't hold any more elements, the vector is resized.

If the capacity would increase by 1 which each new `push_back`, massive overhead would occur.

Comment: The size does increase by 1 for each `push_back`. The capacity may increase by more, but I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: @interjay "but consistently adds 6 extra cells to the vector" what other cause could there be?

Comment: The question isn't clear, but I assume that `push_back` isn't called the amount of times that the OP expects it to be called.

Comment: @Robᵩ I noticed that after Argeman's answer. I guess I assumed that was part of the code or a behavior that could have easily been spotted while debugging. But yeah, that's probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
vec1.push_back(input_word);
```

within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is this function that is adding the extra elements? Have you traced it through with a debugger? Presumably you're checking `size()` rather than `capacity()` on the vector both directly before and after the call? What happens if none of your 'special' characters are in the input string?

I notice that in your `else` block, you are potentially assigning a blank `temp_str` to the object pushed onto the vector. Maybe this has something to do with it?